# Iterate through JSON Array and show result in a HTML table

Tags: c#, javascript, html, jquery

I try to iterate through an array and show the results in a HTML table. The Data is coming from a webservice.

My JavaScript function:

```
function loadDate() {

        var PanelID = document.getElementById('PanelID').value;
        alert(PanelID);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../WebService/QRCode.asmx/getDatetime",
            data: "{ 'PanelID': '" + PanelID + "' }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            cache: true,
            success: function(data) {

                var table = document.createElement('table');
                var str = '<table>';
                str += '<tr><th>Von</th><th>Bis</th><th>Thema</th></tr>';

                for(var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

                    str += '<tr><td>' + data.d[i].Von + '</td><td>' + data.d[i].Bis + '</td><td>' + data.d[i].Thema + '</td></tr>';

                }
                str += '</table>';
                return str;


                var existingDiv = document.getElementById('DataTable');
                existingDiv.innerHTML = loadDate(data);

            },
            error: function(x, e) {
                alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

HTML Part

```
 <body>
    <h1>
        Check-In und Check-Out von Besprechungen</h1>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div id = "DataTable"> </div>
    <p>
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        Raumname: 
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox type="text" name="Panels" ID="PanelID" value="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox type="text" ID="Table" mode="multiline" runat="server" Coloumns="100" Rows="200"
            Height="230px" Width="405px"></asp:TextBox>


        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" Text="Check-In" Width="99px" OnClientClick="return loadDate();" />
        <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Check_Out" Width="99px" />
    </p>
    </form> 
</body>
```

The Problem is that something is not working in my code. If I do it with the above code I can't display the values.

I think it has something to do wit the for clause, because

f i change the FOR clause for example:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    var VonDatum = data.d[i].Von;
                    $("#Table").val(VonDatum);  
}
```

so I can display the Von value in a textbox. But if I do it like that the FOR clause is displaying only one value, but there are more than 30 values in the array.

My JSON-Data looks like:

```
{"d":[{"Von":"18.05.2012 00:00:00","Bis":"18.06.2012 00:00:00","Thema":"Raum ist gesperrt","PanelIDs":"FAT-1"}]}
```

Comment: What does the json data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OLD**

```
return str;

var existingDiv = document.getElementById('DataTable');
existingDiv.innerHTML = loadDate(data);
```

**NEW**

```
var existingDiv = document.getElementById('DataTable');
existingDiv.innerHTML = loadDate(data);

return str;
```

but your `str` not set in any element so *you want to set element* ?
    like this way

```
var existingDiv = document.getElementById('DataTable');
    existingDiv.innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: hey thanks that is working so far. He loads the table with the Data, but after 2 sec the Table dissappears. That strange

Comment: Maybe you know what can cause that the table disappars after 2 sec?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have

```
return str;
```

Where are you returning it to? Should your code be

```
existingDiv.innerHTML = loadDate(str);
```